# Need a searchbox using clarity angular with input container

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity, clarity

Im trying to build a search bar with an embedded X button. Im using clarity with angular. Clarity doesnt provide a component directly matching my needs.

However I came across 2 components viz, clr-password-container and clr-date-container which look similar to what i want.

https://github.com/vmware/clarity/blob/master/packages/angular/projects/clr-angular/src/forms/datepicker/date-container.ts

But its not rendering my searchbox the way it renders the clr-date-container or the clr-password-container.
Here is what Im getting:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-form-reset-wrmqn4
Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in grid to layout the form controls.

Here is the form markup:

```
    <form class="clr-form">
        <div class="clr-control-container">
            <div class="clr-input-wrapper clr-row">
                <input clrInput placeholder="Filter your list here..." name="filter" [(ngModel)]="filter" class="clr-col-10"/>
                <button class="clr-input-group-icon-action" type="button">
          <clr-icon shape="times" title="filter" class="searchbar-input"></clr-icon>
      </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Keep in mind if you are using the Angular forms `clrForm` then some of the classes (`.clr-form`) will be added automatically. The important thing to note here is that I added `.clr-row` to the input wrapper and then the respoctive classes to the input and the button.

Here is a working stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-form-reset-9aguhf